# Release job on Heroku randomly stops sending Files over FTP

Tags: heroku, ftp

I have an app release process that has been working fine for a week or two and has now randomly stopped working.
My npm app is built with Heroku and a release job then runs that FTPs the static files to another host. I use the [npm ftp library](https://www.npmjs.com/package/ftp) to do this. This has randomly stopped working with a timeout error:

```
Error: Timeout while connecting to server
    at Timeout._onTimeout (/app/node_modules/ftp/lib/connection.js:304:24)
    at ontimeout (timers.js:436:11)
    at tryOnTimeout (timers.js:300:5)
    at listOnTimeout (timers.js:263:5)
    at Timer.processTimers (timers.js:223:10)
```

the [release script](https://github.com/Roaders/cineworld-planner/blob/master/src/node/release/index.ts) is as follows:

```
const DIST_PATH = `dist/cineworld-planner`;
const filesList = readdirSync(join(process.cwd(), DIST_PATH));

const client = new Client();

function pushFiles() {
    const putFile = bindNodeCallback(client.put.bind(client));

    from(filesList).pipe(
        mergeMap(fileName => {
            const localPath = join(process.cwd(), DIST_PATH, fileName);
            console.log(`Putting path ${localPath} to remote ${fileName}`);
            return putFile(localPath, fileName);
        }, 1)
    ).subscribe({
        complete: () => client.end()
    });
}

client.on('ready', () => {
    console.log(`READY`);
    pushFiles();
});

client.on('error', (error: any) => {
    const code = error.code || 'NO_CODE';

    console.log(`ERROR: ${code}`);

    console.log(error);

    process.exit(1);
});

client.connect({
    user: process.env.FTP_USER,
    host: process.env.FTP_HOST,
    password: process.env.FTP_PASSWORD
});
```

I have asked my host if there are any issues but all they have said is that the IP address that my script reported it was running on was not blocked.

I have tested the script from my home PC and it also works fine from there.

This will be a major pain if this has stopped working. I really don't know what else to try.

Any help very gratefully received.

Answer (score 0):

It turns out that for me the fix was as simple as increasing the timeout:

```
const connectOptions: Options = {
    user: process.env.FTP_USER,
    host: process.env.FTP_HOST,
    password: process.env.FTP_PASSWORD,
    connTimeout: 60000,
    pasvTimeout: 60000,
};

client.connect(connectOptions);
```